# Django single object update in for loop

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Hi I'm wondering if it possible or how to update single model object name inside for loop by his id using `object.filter(pk=id).update(name='name')` function
I try to do this  but its not working in for loop. It's working only outside loop

**EDIT**

my edit view with for loop:
first i prepare data based on my database.Data can be modified by other methods so i keep they in global list schedule_table.
When I'm saving project object i want to update other data representing by schedule_table, using for loop.

```
def ProjectEditView(request, pk):

project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=17)

schedule_table_load_form_db(project)#preparing list with data
Task_Schedule_TableView(request)

project_form = ProjectForm(request.POST or None, instance=project)

project_form_valid = project_form.is_valid()

if project_form_valid:
    with transaction.atomic():

        # save form in DB
        project = project_form.save(commit=False)
        project.save()

        # modify other object based on changed list schedule_table
        if schedule_table.__len__() > 0:
            #my for loop
            for p in schedule_table:
                team = Team.objects.get(name=p.team)

                phase = Phase.objects.filter(pk=p.pk).update(name=p.name,
                                                             project=project,
                                                             team=team,
                                                             order=p.order,
                                                             duration=p.duration,
                                                             prev=p.prev,
                                                             start=p.start,
                                                             end=p.end)



    # some other staff..... outside the loop

    return redirect('Project:ProjectListView')

context = {'project_form': project_form}
return render(request, 'Project/test.html', context)
```

function to prepare list with data:

```
def schedule_table_load_form_db(project):
global schedule_table
schedule_table = []

phases = Phase.objects.filter(project=project)
for phase in phases:
    tasks_list = Task.objects.filter(phase=phase)
    tasks = []
    for task in tasks_list:
        task_dict = Task_dictionary.objects.get(pk=task.task_dictionary.pk)
        tmp = ''
        for e in task.employers.employer.all():
            user = User.objects.get(pk=e.user_id)
            tmp += user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name + ','
        tasks.append(TableTask(pk=task.pk,
                               order=task.order,
                               name=task.name,
                               duration=task.duration,
                               employer=tmp,
                               start=task.start,
                               end=task.end,
                               min_employers_nr=task_dict.min_employers_nr,
                               max_employers_nr=task_dict.max_employers_nr,
                               prev=task.prev_task,
                               ))

    schedule_table.append(TablePhase(pk=phase.pk,
                                     name=phase.name,
                                     duration=0.0,
                                     start=phase.start,
                                     end=phase.end,
                                     team=phase.team.name,
                                     task=tasks,
                                     order=schedule_table.__len__(),
                                     prev=phase.prev
                                     ))
```

Comment: Yes that is possible. Are you sure that the collection over which you loop contains any elements? Because if you loop over an empty collection, the body is *never* executed.

Comment: i have object list with variables : id and new_values representing object to update and his new value, but when i iterate over that list update not working

Comment: `for item in list:`
   `appobj= app.object.get(pk=id)`
    `appobj.name=item`
    `appobj.save()`
you mean something Like above? @ProgShiled

Comment: You'll need to show some code that includes the loop, and some context about what it is doing.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've just add some code with loop

Comment: @Roshan i try this solution and still the same situation

Comment: ` Phase.objects.filter(pk=p.pk) `, is `p.pk` giving primary key to filter?
can you print it ? Do `schedule_table` holds objects? @ProgShiled

Comment: Yes p.pk is primary key , yes i can print it , yest schedule_table holds objects. And funny is that if i print item value from DB after update instruction it show me changed value but in DB is still old one